# Recursively Add to list in Clojure

Tags: list, recursion, clojure, append

I'm trying to recursively append a list in clojure.  It is to deconstruct a POW function that I created, turning (POW x 3) into (* x (* x x))

I'm a really novice Clojure programmer, and attempting to wrap my head around this problem in Clojure is kind of tough.  I have come up with:

```
(defn do-it [x n]
  (if (= n 0)
  (println x)
  ((dec n) (if (= x 'x))
     (list '* 'x 'x)
     (list '* 'x x))))
```

Which will not compile or run, but that is where my plan is going.  My idea is to decrease n every time you add another (* x  to the list.

I have this, which is similar to what I'm trying to do, but does not implement the POW idea into the function:

```
(defn do-it [x]
  (if (= x 'x)
    (list '* 'x 'x)
    (list '* 'x x)))
```

Am I on the right path with the first piece of code?  Is what I'm trying even possible?

Comment: Do you want to get `expression` or `value` of your result?

Comment: Expression, if I understood your question/what you meant.

Answer (score 4):

Your posted efforts are pretty far off the mark, I'm afraid. If I were going to write pow by hand, it would look like this:

```
(defn pow [x n]
  (if (= n 1)
    x
    (list '* x (pow x (dec n)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify problem if notice that prefix notation can take various number of arguments. Then your function looks like this:

```
(defn power [x n]
  (cons '* (repeat n x)))

(power 2 3) => (* 2 2 2)
(power 'x 2) => (* x x)
```

Zero and One base cases covered also, because:

```
(power 2 1) => (* 2) ; valid result, produces 2
(power 2 0) => (*) ; valid result, produces 1
```

Comment: the input requires it only take two arguments. Because of this, (* x x x) is invalid. It needs to be (* x (* x x))

Comment: if it invalid because of condition "only take two arguments" use @amalloy solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn do-it [x n]
  (if (= 1 n)
    x
    (reduce (fn [chain _] `(~'* ~chain))
            `(~'* ~x ~x)
            (range 2 n))))

(do-it 5 10) ->
(* (* (* (* (* (* (* (* (* 5 5)))))))))

(do-it 5 1) ->
5
```